# SQL query missing select statement fetching data error

Tags: sql

I am using SQL query fetching some issue data is not fetching black show.

I am sharing this query here. Please help me.

**SQL query here**

```
select * from products where hitproduct='0'  ORDER BY id DESC and  user_id='$user_id'
```

Comment: If you want to order by more than one column (expression) use comma (`,`) not `AND`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL query only has one `where` clause.  Presumably, you intend:

```
select p.*
from products p
where user_id = ? and
      hitproduct = 0 -- looks like a number, so I assume it is
order by id desc;
```

Note the use of `?`.  This represents a *parameter placeholder*.  Don't munge query strings with parameters values!  Learn to use parameters properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your given query `and user_id='$user_id'` should be before `ORDER BY`.

```
 select * 
 from products 
 where hitproduct='0' and user_id='$user_id' 
 ORDER BY id DESC
```